# Php Echo Multiple Rows In A Random Order

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 MySql Tables. Videos and Photos. When a user uploads a file it gets stored in one of the tables depending on the file.

heres the code:

### index.php:

```
getVideos($conn);
getPhotos($conn);
```

### get.inc.php:

```
function getVideos($conn) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY date desc";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<div class='video-box'><p>";

echo $row['title']."<br>";

echo "by:";

    echo $row['uid']."<br>";

echo $row ['videofile'];

echo "</p>";
}
}

function getPhotos($conn) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY date desc";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<div class='photo-box'><p>";

echo $row['title']."<br>";

echo "by:";

    echo $row['uid']."<br>";

echo $row ['photofile'];

echo "</p>";
}
}
```

- there are 3 videos and 2 photos in my database curently *

When I have the code as I do Now all 3 of the videos from my database appear first on the the home page then when you slide down the 2 photos appear at the bottom.

How do I make it So the photos and videos are mix and are dispalyed by the date they were uploaded (newest at the top older at the bottom.) Without them being separated like they are now. Please Help.
 - Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the reason for two tables? You could have used just one table and avoid all the problems you are facing now.

Comment: don't echo them immediately. Get all the data, put it into one array, then put it in order, then echo it. Or as pointed out already, just have one table for media. If you need to distinguish the type for any purpose then have a "type" column where you have a value that indicates photo/video. Then you can use SQL ORDER BY to get it in the right date order.

Comment: Kevin, You can union it by Selecting the two tables and order by desc but the video and photos combined in 1 function,  and you split it. for that you split by PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UNION

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT id, date, videofile as file FROM videos
UNION
SELECT id, date, photofile as file FROM photos) t
ORDER BY t.date;
```

Here you can play with example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92c8fc/1/0

Altough it is possible it will probably be better to store this information just in one table. If you need to preserve information about what is video file and what is photo you can just add another column where you store this kind of meta data.